# How to use High Availability in JBOS AS 7?

Tags: jboss, cluster-computing, high-availability

How I can start a cluster in JBoss AS 7 ? I can star and use ( deploy and etc ), but how can I configure a cluster ? I used the configuration HA in standalone and each instance is independent. In domain mode I can use a group in HA profile, but I thinks that's not the way. I saw  the webinars , but I cant see what configuratin do.
Please, help ! :P

Answer (score 2):

I've written a step-by-step guide here to show people how to setup a JBoss AS7 cluster in domain control mode:

https://community.jboss.org/wiki/AS7ClusterHowto

Comment: Guide needs to be updated for AS 7.2 and also be clear on what needs to be done with multiple JBoss clusters on the same network. Wastes tons of time figuring out something that should be in the guide.

Answer (score 1):

Standalone mode is exactly the same as the old cluster mode in JBoss 4.2.3 and JBoss 5. The difference between that the JBoss 7 Domain is the Domain model works like MySQL domain clustering, in that the domain server stores all the cluster data centrally and the Nodes call call into the domain to pick up their configurations. If you do not have a domain controller, you have to manually configure each box, just like before.

Answer (score 1):

We have written a series of articles about the cluster capabilities in JBoss AS 7.

The first post shows how to cluster a simple Java EE application with the JBoss AS7 and explains [the basic concepts behind clustering capabilities of the AS7](http://blog.akquinet.de/2012/06/21/clustering-in-jboss-as7eap-6/).

The second post explains how to manage multiple server instances in a clustered environment. It contains how to setup the [domain mode and deploying applications to multiple servers with the command line interface](http://blog.akquinet.de/2012/06/29/managing-cluster-nodes-in-domain-mode-of-jboss-as-7-eap-6/).

The third blog post of a JBoss AS7 / EAP 6 series covers [how to setup up different JBoss cluster topologies](http://blog.akquinet.de/2012/07/19/scalable-ha-clustering-with-jboss-as-7-eap-6/) and explain the challenge to make a cluster highly available and scalable.

Maybe it is of some help.

Answer (score 1):

We have written a large set of tutorials about [JBoss clustering](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-cluster) that are complimentary to the official documentation.
In particular this is a tutorial about [JBoss AS 7 clustering](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-cluster/clustering-jboss-as-7) which shows how to start a cluster of servers and configuring Apache Web server to reach JBoss AS 7 cluster.
You can find also some tutorials about [Configuring mod_cluster with jBoss](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-cluster/clustering-with-jboss-mod_cluster) covering several application server releases.
If you want to have a look at [JBoss AS 7 HA Configuration](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-cluster/jboss-as-7-ha-tutorial) you can find one useful resource as well.
Regards